# Why does this simple code not work in JSfiddle?

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I did this in JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jocelynwang205/qSjn6/

It is supposed to turn a paragraph black, but it seems that the function cannot be called. It does not work on a real webpage either.

Later I added my JavaScript to the html in JSfiddle, like this:

```
<script>
function changeA(){
document.getElementById('para1').style.color ='black';
}
</script>
<p id="para1">
This is a paragraph to be changed.
</p>
<a href="#" onclick="changeA(); return false">Turn black.</a>
```

And it worked: http://jsfiddle.net/jocelynwang205/qSjn6/1/

So I want to know why. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean the fiddle doesn't work? When you click the link the color changes. Make sure you put the JavaScript in the head of your real web page and not in the onload event.

Comment: @j08691: The fiddle link was wrong, I fixed the question.

Comment: @BoltClock - OK but the original link (http://jsfiddle.net/jocelynwang205/qSjn6/1/) works fine if the jsFiddle is constructed properly: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/v8FQx/.

Comment: the original doesnt work because you have `onlick` instead of `onclick`, and do not have the code running in the `head` but in a onload function (settings are on the left side) causing the function to be invisible to the onclick attr

Comment: @PatrickEvans even if you correct that typo it's still not working.

Comment: @Patrick Evans: You can post that as an answer.

Comment: @C-link, as i mention he would also have to change the JSFiddle setting to run the js code in the head instead of the onload function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the original doesnt work because you have onlick instead of onclick, and do not have the code running in the head but in a onload function (settings are on the left side) causing the function to be invisible to the onclick attr

JSFiddle defaults to the javascript being run in a onLoad function so basically your code was being run like below:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  function changeA(){
    document.getElementById('para1').style.color ='black';
  } 
};
<script>
```

which makes the function `changeA` invisible to the html onclick attribute
changing the setting to "no wrap - in head" makes it run like:

```
<script>
function changeA(){
  document.getElementById('para1').style.color ='black';
} 
<script>
```

which now makes it visible to the html

Below is a screenshot of where the setting is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in the jsfiddle you specified **onlick** instead of **onClick**.

```
<a href="#" onlick="changeA(); return false">Turn black.</a>
```

change it to

```
<a href="#" onClick="changeA(); return false">Turn black.</a>
```

in the link, and set option **No wrap in**  from left hand side of jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #para1
        {
            color: red;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeA()
        {
            document.getElementById('para1').style.color ='black';
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <p id="para1">This is a paragraph to be changed.</p>
    <a href="#" onclick="changeA(); return false">Turn black.</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Try this.